# Можно ли открыть ссылку на мобильном устройстве в новой вкладке, а не приложение

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка - https://qr.nspk.ru/AS10001NHL49JPAE95KR3MVIRODI7F5D?type=01&bank=100000000006&sum=101&cur=RUB&crc=5EEF которая при нажатии на мобильном устройстве открывает приложение банка, но при копировании ее в адрес в браузере, открывает страницу выбора банка.
Пробую открыть эту ссылку через window.open(ссылка) и мобилы открывают приложение банка сразу (если приложений 2 или больше то выбрать нельзя открывается какое-то по дефолту).
Вопрос можно как то мобильному браузеру сказать открывать ссылку только в новой вкладке?
Пробовал:

1. window.open(ссылка, '_blank')
2. window.location.href = ссылка
3. даже через мега костыль

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
            target: '_blank',
            href: ссылка,
        }).click()
```

Результат один - открывается приложение вместо новой вкладки в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю что не так, ведь есть простой способ:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">lorem ipsum</a>
```